# Reinitialize Windows Event Log service without reboot

Tags: windows, winapi, event-log, service-control-manager

I am working on application which logs to a custom event log. Application was recently rebranded, and the name of event log has changed (from "CompanyA Events" to "CompanyB Events"). The name(s) of event log sources ("Subsystem1", "Subsystem2", etc) did not change. Application installer removes the old log entries from registry and writes the new ones.

I noticed, that in some environments (happens a lot on 2008 R2) the logging stops, and no events are being written. Sometimes events are actually written to the OLD evtx file, which was supposed to be removed. Following fixes the problem:

- reboot machine
- restart "Windows Event Log" service

Latter action cannot be achieved using SCM because of access denied, even though I'm an administrator. However, killing the process works, and I cam start the "Windows Event Log" service, after which event logging works normally.

**Question:** how do I re-initialize event log service without killing process or rebooting the machine? Is there some sort of documented or undocumented call, which I could use to signal event log service that it should re-read its configuration?

Comment: task scheduler service is a dependency because of which event log service is not able to restart.

Comment: @Vijay Acces denied is the reason because of which event log service is not able to restart

Comment: Actually @Vijay is right. The access denied message is because you cannot re-start "Task scheduler Service". If you try through services console all the actions for the "Task scheduler Service" are disabled. I have the same problem, if you have found anything please share. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Just for the record, as this is an old question: I had this problem also, and [Christo's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169529/reinitialize-windows-event-log-service-without-reboot#comment46531068_19169529) has put me into the path for the solution:

- using `psexec -s net stop schedule` (so, I stopped the task scheduler service with the system account),
- I then was able to restart the eventlog service.
- Once restarted, I just used again `psexec -s net start schedule`. Way to go.

You may need to download psexec from Microsoft.